# Date as class in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am looking for a way to make each td in the datepicker unique. I have set a price under each highlighted date but the problem is that the price is the same on every date.

```
addCustomInformation : function(x) {
            window.bookingRequest.totalPrice = 0;
            window.bookingRequest.totalAccommodationOnlyPrice = 0;
            window.rateTableRowIndex = 0;

            var selectedTimeFrom = x;
            var selectedTimeTo = x + 604800000;

            while (selectedTimeFrom < selectedTimeTo) {
                accommodations.buildRateRow(selectedTimeFrom, 1, 0, 3);
                    selectedTimeFrom += (86400000 * 7);
            }

            var price = accommodations.formatPrice(window.bookingRequest.totalAccommodationOnlyPrice);
            var newprice = price.substring(3);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".ui-datepicker-calendar td").filter(function() {
                  var date = $(this).text();
                  return /\d/.test(date);
                }).find("a").attr('data-custom', newprice); // Add custom data here
                }, 0)
    }
```

This code fetches the price but the price is assigned to ".ui-datepicker-calendar td" which it should not. I want it to add the price to the current td in the calendar loop. The addCustomInformation function run on every highlighted td.

My thought was to add the date as a class for each td so it would look something like this

```
<td class="05-08-2016 dp-highlight"></td>
<td class="06-08-2016 dp-highlight"></td>
```

Can not figure out how to do this. If it can be done I could send the current date in the loop as a parameter to the function and add the price to the correct td.

I can not use return in "beforeShowDay" because this is used to return the different classes for highlighted and disabled dates. Adding the class in a current return like return [true, 'dp-highlight current-date'] is also not possible as I can not run the addCustomInformation function after the return.

x in the function is the current date in miliseconds used to calculate the price.

Any other solution would also be welcome.

Michael

Comment: Instead of making date as class.consider making it an attribute store date as data-date-value="05-08-2016"

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. Any idea on how to do this and where in the code?

Comment: While you are creating td add a data attribute data-date

Comment: Cant  figure out where each td is added. Should not be that difficult but I am not a javascript expert and can not find anywhere in the code where the td is created.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle with your markup and js code..it would be helpful for me to understand and help u

Comment: I will try and work a bit more with a solution. The js file is part of a big booking system. I cant copy out just a part of the code. It wouldn't work. If I do not come up with a solution  I will get back to you. Thanks for your time so far :)

Answer (score 0):

In the datepicker file i managed to get a id added to each active/clickable td in the calendar. My custom function now looks like this:

```
addCustomInformation : function(currentday, dateclass) {
            window.bookingRequest.totalAccommodationOnlyPrice = 0;
            window.rateTableRowIndex = 0;

            var selectedTimeFrom = currentday;
            var selectedTimeTo = currentday + 604800000 // the day one week from current day ;

            while (selectedTimeFrom < selectedTimeTo) {
                accommodations.buildRateRow(selectedTimeFrom, 1, 0, 3);
                    selectedTimeFrom += (86400000 * 7);
            }

            var price = accommodations.formatPrice(window.bookingRequest.totalAccommodationOnlyPrice);
            var newprice = price.substring(4) // remove DKK from price;

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("." + dateclass).text('DKK ' + newprice) // add the price to the td;
            },1000)
```

Take a look at this page http://designunivers.dk/green2green/hotel/hotel-isla-canela-golf/ and chose the tab "Priser og bestilling". Next press the "Vælg datoer" button in fx "Billund - Sevilla". In the calendar go to the months february, march, april. Sometimes the price shows DKK 0 and other times it shows the correct price. If you refresh the page and try again it shows the price on some of the dates that returned DKK 0 before. Totally weird.

Any ideas on the problem? Is it because the "newprice" variable is not yet calculated before I add it to the td field? Any solutions on this in such case?